# jQuery on function is getting bound to the container, why so?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery code

```
$('tbody').on("click",$('vote'+rowCount),function(){alert('hi');});
```

but the alert shows up when i click anywhere on the table body instead of just showing up on clicking the selector
Why is this happening?

----Edit---

Got it working by writing the element as "#vote"+rowCount instead of writing as $('vote'+rowCount)
But there is another weird problem -
I am creating dynamic rows with this code, but whatever i type in the value of the textbox remains empty (as initialized), why so

```
$('#add_ans').click(function(){
    var rowCount = $('table tbody tr').length + 1;
    var rowString = '<tr>\
                        <td><div class="span_5"><span class="badge badge-success">'+rowCount+'</span></div></td>\
                        <td><div class="span3"><input type="text" class="input-large" value="" /></div></td>\
                        <td><div class="span2 pull-right"><b>0</b></div></td>\
                        <td><div class="span2"><button class="btn btn-success" id="vote'+rowCount+'"><b>Vote!</b> <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></button></div></td>\
                        <td><div class="span2"><button class="btn btn-info" disabled><b>Reviews</b> <i class="icon-ok-circle"></i></button></div></td>\
                    </tr>'
    $('tbody').append(rowString);
    $('tbody').on("click","#vote"+rowCount,voteOption);
});
```

and the event handler is

```
function voteOption(){            
        var rowCount = $('tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
        alert(rowCount);
        var ans = $('tr:eq('+rowCount+') .input-large').attr('value');
        alert(ans);
}
```

Comment: `$('vote'+rowCount)` would be matching invalid `<vote>` elements, and the argument should be a selector, not a jQuery wrapper. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: What do you expect `$('vote'+rowCount)` to select?

Comment: actually vote1, vote2 etc are the ids of a button
i want to bind the click functionality on a button

Comment: if they're ids then you want `'#vote' + rowCount`

Answer (score 3):

This is because the second argument is selector (string), not an element selected by `$()`.
`$('vote'+rowCount)` is not correct and the `.on()` click event will be fired anywhere you click because the `.on` event is actually bind to the `<tbody>`.

For example, this will match the `<div>` inside the `<tbody>` and bind the click event to it.

```
$('tbody').on("click", 'div' ,function(){alert('hi');});
```

Here is the code example....

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="createBtn" value="Create"/>
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody id="mytableBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var i = 0;
    $("#createBtn").click(function()
    {
        var newRow = $("<tr></tr>").attr("id", "row"+i);
        var btn = $("<button>Vote</button>").attr("id", "vote"+i);
        var col = $("<td><span>Video "+i+"</span></td>");
        col.append(btn);
        newRow.append(col);
        $("#mytable tbody").append(newRow);
        i++;
    });
    $('#mytable tbody').on("click", "button", function(){
        alert(this.id);
        if(this.id == 'vote0')
        {
            alert("Thanks for voting for video 0.");
        }
        else if(this.id == 'vote1')
        {
            alert("Thanks for voting for video 1.");
        }
        else
        {
            // handle the rest....
        }
    });
});
```

You can also find this in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33Wny/1/

Comment: Hello,thanks for the help but even this line below is not working
kindly suggest how can i select an element when its id has to be dynamically created
    $('tbody').on("click",$(':button[id=vote'+rowCount+']'),function(){

Comment: don't use $(':button[id=vote'+rowCount+']') as selector, it is incorrect!

Comment: can u tell me what is wrong with it? i have used it else where also and it works :(

Comment: According to the API document in http://api.jquery.com/on/ the type of the selector is 'string'

Comment: Thanks Derek for the code, but i have a doubt ... you have used if and else to handle the selection. Is there any way i can select the button group using jquery selector? i have 2 sets of buttons one for voting and one to see the reviews ... 
i want to attach the event to onclick of the vote button group

Comment: Hi derek, i got it working by changing the code to this
$('tbody').on("click","#vote"+rowCount,function(){